# What other distributions provide the option to install inside Windows?

Tags: wubi

I mean installing with something like wubi? Can Fedora do this?

Comment: This is Ask Ubuntu, not Ask GNU/Linux operating systems. You might instead be interested in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) which is a sister site to Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know only ubuntu has this option.
But nearly every Distribution offers the alongside windows option